# How to send messages from main to page-worker using Addon SDK

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

this is my main.js

```
var background = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
    contentScriptWhen:'start',
    contentScriptFile: ['./jquery.min.js','./socket.io1.js', './background.js'],
    onMessage: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```

and my background.js

```
var myuser={}
//other socket.io stuff
```

How do I send messages from **main.js-> background.js** and from **background.js->main.js** ?

(port ? postMessage ?): any available sample ?

Comment: Im not too good with sdk stuff, but does this help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29

Comment: Already read that with no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**main.js**

```
// keep track of your active workers
var workers = [];

require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen:'start',
    contentScriptFile: ['./jquery.min.js','./socket.io1.js', './background.js'],
    onAttach: function(worker){

        workers.push(worker);

        worker.on("message", function(aData){
            //messages from background.js
        });

        //remove inactive workers
        worker.on("detach", function(){
            workers.splice(workers.indexOf(worker), 1);
        });

        //messages to background.js 
        worker.postMessage({
            johnny : "oh, hi mark", 
            mark   : "oh, hi johnny"
        });
    }
});
```

**background.js**

```
self.on("message", function(msg){
    //messages from main.js 
});

//messages to main.js   
function post(msg){
    self.postMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: What is include: "*" for ?

Comment: The will inject your content scripts in all URLs. You could use one or more (include also takes an array) specific regular expressions that match only your URLs.

Comment: Is `self` defined by default or do I have to `require` it?

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/self): `self` is a global object available to content scripts. You might be mixing it up with the [sdk's self module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self).